# Openfire Service Starting then crashing on CentOS

Tags: centos

I have an Openfire installation that has worked fine for a couple years, but we were recently trying to clone the physical machine to a virtual machine. We couldn't even get to cloning, because we couldn't boot the USB. I tried turning it off and back on a number of times to try to get into the USB. However, since performing multiple power cycles, the CentOS installation comes up, I can SSH into it, and when I do

```
service openfire start
```

It will run for about 30 seconds, not even, and then when running

```
service openfire status
```

it comes up

```
openfire is not running
```

chkconfig shows OFF OFF ON ON ON OFF (levels 1 through 6)

I'm just not sure where to go from here other than rebuild the box.

Comment: you should try to run openfire from the command line to see what errors make it crash

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running from ssh. When i run it physically at the machine, I don't get anything either. It never tells me why the service crashes.